# What is the full version of the number: 1.7976931348623158E+308?

Tags: floating-point, numbers

I've been searching on the internet and found 1.7976931348623158E+308 as the highest float value. Can I please have the full version?

Comment: Note `1.7976931348623157E+308` is a closer approximation than `1.7976931348623158E+308`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approximate value of a common `DBL_MAX` is

```
printf("%.*e\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG-1, DBL_MAX);
// 1.7976931348623157e+308
```

Usually, `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` (e.g. 17) significant decimal digits is sufficient.

The [exactly value](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/212490/29485)  of a common `DBL_MAX` is
179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.0

---

To find the exact value in hexadecimal significant / decimal base 2 exponent, use

```
printf("%a\n", DBL_MAX);
// 0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023
```

Comment: `DBL_MAX`? OP hasn't indicated a language, a platform, a standard, or even a planet. All we know is "floating point"

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed!

Comment: There are two types of people in the world: those who can draw good conclusions from incomplete data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "full version," but here's how the maximum double-precision value is represented assuming the IEEE-754 format:

```
 VALUE = 1.7976931348623157e308 :: Double
                  6    5          4         3         2         1         0
                  3 21098765432 1098765432109876543210987654321098765432109876543210
                  S ----E11---- ------------------------S52-------------------------
   Binary layout: 0 11111111110 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
      Hex layout: 7FEF FFFF FFFF FFFF
       Precision: Double
            Sign: Positive
        Exponent: 1023 (Stored: 2046, Bias: 1023)
  Classification: FP_NORMAL
          Binary: 0b1.1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111p+1023
           Octal: 0o1.777777777777777774p+1023
         Decimal: 1.7976931348623157e308
             Hex: 0xF.FFFFFFFFFFFF8p+1020
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a shorter form, IEEE754 max (finite) double is `2^1024 - 2^(1024-53)`.

Use whatever large integer arithmetic package to print that.